# How to get the latest commit date of a file from a given github reposotiry?

Tags: shell, shell-script, github

Given a file in a Github repository such as `https://github.com/user/project-name/blob/master/filename`, and I wrote a shell script (or a function in a shell script) to download this file called `filename` (`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/project-name/master/filename`), if the file already exists in my local path, then I could just check the latest modification date of the file.

If the date is newer than the date which is already written into the file, I should just remove the old file and download it from GitHub repository directly, or else, I should do nothing.

How can I do it in shell script?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about this, but after more searches, I solved it according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204589/1528712

Which in my case, the solution would be:

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/user/project-name/commits?path=filename&page=1&per_page=1" | jq -r '.[0].commit.committer.date'
```